# How to know whether you're enrolled to Windows 10 flighting programmatically?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview

In my domain-joined Windows 10 machine at work, I suspect my employer set it up for Windows 10 flighting. In `Windows Update Advanced options`, The option to flight doesn't appear at all (see screenshot below).

How can I see the flighting options programmatically - by running some script, read some registry etc?

[image: Advanced Updates - no flighting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the flighting info is in the registry. My employer appears to have disabled it for everyone by putting this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsSelfHost\Applicability]
"ThresholdFlightsDisabled"=dword:00000001
"BranchName"="(redacted) DOESNT WANT ME FLIGHTING"
"UserPreferredBranchName"="(redacted) DOESNT WANT ME FLIGHTING"
```

In another machine I do have the flighting UI, and enabling it puts different stuff in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsSelfHost\Applicability]
"EnablePreviewBuilds"=dword:00000001
"Ring"=...
"BranchName"=...
// lots of other stuff
```

In that machine, `bcdedit` also lists flighting:

```
(...)
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
(...)
flightsigning           Yes
(...)
```